# how can i retrieve a list of currently open workbooks and get VBA to put them in a mulitple choice dialouge box?

Tags: vba, excel

Good morning. so in essence i have built a whole bunch of macros that work fine after a lot of work. trouble i have is the macros will always need to perform actions on other workbooks ie: "macro workbook" contains macros that perform actions on "January 2018 data". The reason for this is that the monthly data sheets are always new so i cant store macros on them.

i personally and happy to open a separate workbook, press f11 and run the correct macro. there may be end users in the future however that are not comfortable with this and so i want to employ the use of a button. obviously by implementing a button on the "macro workbook", it applies the macros function to the macro workbook, not the intended one.

In an ideal world i want to press the macro button and be presented with a list of currently opened workbooks that the user can read through and select the correct workbook. it will then select this open workbook and then continue with the macro.

Is this even possible? I'm new to VBA but i have never come across this before. the closest fix i can think of is to ask the user to input the file directory and name in a dialogue box, then use that to select the workbook to continue running the macro, such as:

Sub macro1()

```
Dim Filepath As String

    Filepath = InputBox("Please enter the filename of workbook you wish to run the macro on", "Enter Filepath")

Workbooks(Filepath).Activate

rest of macro can then continue...

End Sub
```

I would just rather the user be able to click the name of the workbook rather than have to input it, to reduce the chance of them inputting it wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is very broad - have a look at [ask], then perhaps [edit] your post to show the code you already have, what you have tried, and the specific problem you are having.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but your question is very broad as of now (which is against SO's rule) - would recommend reading the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section - either way, I'd recommend looking into [`Workbook.Open()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.open) function and [`Workbooks`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks)  collection object, which returns a collection (something like an array) of all the currently open Workbooks

Comment: I recommend to [create an Excel Add-in](https://trumpexcel.com/excel-add-in/) for that so you can use it on any `ActiveWorkbook` then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many ways that this could be implemented. Here is a very simple way which might give you at least one idea. In your main workbook with "your macros" … create UserForm with a Combobox and a Button on it … like the following:

[image: UserForm]

Add the following code in the UserForm:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim vWorkbook As Workbook
    ComboBox1.Clear
    For Each vWorkbook In Workbooks
        ComboBox1.AddItem vWorkbook.Name
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If ComboBox1.ListIndex <> -1 Then
        Call YourMacro(ComboBox1)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub YourMacro(vWorkbookName As String)
    MsgBox Workbooks(vWorkbookName).Name
End Sub
```

Then create a module so that when you bring up the macro dialog box there a macro to load the form.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub LoadForm()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

When the form is activated, the code loads the names of the currently open workbooks into the ComboBox. You can select one. Click the button … and after it checks that a workbook has been selected, it runs an example macro which is mimicking your own macro (which in this example displays the workbook name by referencing the Workbooks object). Because clearly in "your" macros … they should be reference the selected Workbook.

Once again … clearly this is very rudimentary. Its intended to one example of what's possible and might point you in the right direction.

Comment: With a little bit of tweaking this was perfect for me. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Another method, this will DO_THIS_MACRO on the also open workbook, if there is only 1 other workbook open.  If there are 2 or more, will cycle through them asking if you want to DO_THIS_MACRO on that workbook, or go to next, or Cancel.

```
Sub DoOnOpenWorkbooks()
    'Define a Workbook Object
    Dim oWb As Workbook, iSh As Worksheet, WkbCount As Double, numa As Integer
    
    'Traverse through each workbook Opened - Using Excel Application Object
    WkbCount = 0

    For Each oWb In Application.Workbooks
        WkbCount = WkbCount + 1
    Next oWb
    ' Do not list PERSONAL and this workbook
    WkbCount = WkbCount - 2
    Debug.Print "WkbCount: " & WkbCount

    'Must be at least 1 other open workbook to continue
    If WkbCount = 0 Then Exit Sub

    For Each oWb In Application.Workbooks
        'Ignore PERSONAL and this workbook
        If oWb.Name <> "PERSONAL.XLSB" And oWb.Name <> ActiveWorkbook.Name Then

            'If only 1 other workbook, do macro on that
            If WkbCount = 1 Then
                Workbooks(oWb.Name).Activate
                DO_THIS_MACRO
                Exit Sub
            End If

            Workbooks(oWb.Name).Activate
            numa = MsgBox("There are " & WkbCount & " workbooks open.  Do this on " & oWb.Name & "?", 3, "DO_THIS_MACRO")
 
            If numa = 6 Then
                ' MsgBox "Yes option pressed!"
                Workbooks(oWb.Name).Activate
                DO_THIS_MACRO
                ' Exit or ask to do on all open
                Exit Sub
            ElseIf numa = 7 Then
                'MsgBox "No option pressed!"
            Else
                '  MsgBox "Cancel pressed!"
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next oWb
End Sub
```